# Compatibility problems with an Command Line executable that´s use WuapiLib

Tags: c#, windows, server, .net-framework-version

First of up, sorry for my english.

I need make a command line executable that could be run in windows servers with .Net 2.0 and newest.
This is my code:

```
sing System;
using WUApiLib;
using System.IO;
using CommandLineParser.Arguments;
using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp;

namespace Windows_Update_Manager
{
    class Program
    {
        //Funcion que busca las actualizciones pendientes
        static public string[] Get_Updates()
        {
            try
            {
                UpdateSession uSession = new UpdateSession();
                IUpdateSearcher uSearcher = uSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
                ISearchResult uResult = uSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'");

                //Console.WriteLine("check");

                if (uResult.Updates.Count <= 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No hay actualizaciones pendientes.");
                    string[] list = {"No hay actualizaciones pendientes."};
                    return list;
                }
                else if (uResult.Updates.Count > 1)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("checkuno");


                    foreach (IUpdate update in uResult.Updates)
                    {
                        string KBstring = update.Title.ToString();
                        string KB = (KBstring.Substring((KBstring.Length -11), 11)).Replace("(","").Replace(")","");
                        Console.WriteLine(update.LastDeploymentChangeTime + " " + update.Title + " " + KB + " " + update.MaxDownloadSize);
                    }
                    //Creamos un array con la lista de actualizaciones
                    string[] list = new string[uResult.Updates.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < uResult.Updates.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string KBstring = uResult.Updates[i].Title.ToString();
                        string KB = (KBstring.Substring((KBstring.Length - 11), 11)).Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "");

                        list[i] = ( uResult.Updates[i].LastDeploymentChangeTime.ToString() +"|"+ uResult.Updates[i].Title.ToString() +"|" + KB + "|"+ (Math.Round((uResult.Updates[i].MaxDownloadSize / 1024 / 1024), 2)).ToString() );
                    } // end for
                    return list;
                }
                else
                {
                    //string[,] list = { { "Error desconocido" }, {""} };
                    string[] list = {"Error desconocido" };
                    return list;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //string[,] list = { {e.ToString() }, {" "} };
                string[] list = {e.ToString()};
                //Si ocurre algún error, lo imprimimos 
                Console.WriteLine("Exception", e);
                return list;
            }
        }

        //Funcion que solo descarga las actualizciones pendientes
        static public void Download_Updates()
        {
            try
            {
                UpdateSession uSession = new UpdateSession();
                IUpdateSearcher uSearcher = uSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
                ISearchResult uResult = uSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'");

                //Console.WriteLine("check");

                if (uResult.Updates.Count < 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No hay actualizaciones pendientes.");
                }
                else if (uResult.Updates.Count > 1)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("checkuno");
                    foreach (IUpdate update in uResult.Updates)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(update.Title);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Descargando actualizaciones...");

                    UpdateDownloader downloader = uSession.CreateUpdateDownloader();
                    //Console.WriteLine("line");
                    downloader.Updates = uResult.Updates;
                    //Console.WriteLine("line2");
                    downloader.Download();
                    //Console.WriteLine("line3");

                    Console.WriteLine("Actualizaciones descargadas.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Si ocurre algún error, lo imprimimos 
                Console.WriteLine("Exception", e);
            }
        }

        //Funcion que instala las atulaizciones pendientes
        static public void Install_Updates()
        {
            try
            {
                UpdateSession uSession = new UpdateSession();
                IUpdateSearcher uSearcher = uSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
                ISearchResult uResult = uSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'");

                //Console.WriteLine("check");

                if (uResult.Updates.Count < 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No hay actualizaciones pendientes.");
                }
                else if (uResult.Updates.Count > 1)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("checkuno");
                    foreach (IUpdate update in uResult.Updates)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(update.Title);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Descargando actualizaciones...");

                    UpdateDownloader downloader = uSession.CreateUpdateDownloader();
                    //Console.WriteLine("line");
                    downloader.Updates = uResult.Updates;
                    //Console.WriteLine("line2");
                    downloader.Download();
                    //Console.WriteLine("line3");

                    Console.WriteLine("Actualizaciones descargadas.");

                    Console.WriteLine("Actualizando Colecciones...");
                    UpdateCollection updatesToInstall = new UpdateCollection();
                    foreach (IUpdate update in uResult.Updates)
                    {
                        if (update.IsDownloaded) updatesToInstall.Add(update);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Instalar actualizaciones recogidas...");
                    IUpdateInstaller installer = uSession.CreateUpdateInstaller();
                    //Console.WriteLine("Check1");
                    installer.Updates = updatesToInstall;
                    //Console.WriteLine("Check2");

                    IInstallationResult installationRes = installer.Install();
                    //Console.WriteLine("Check3");
                    for (int i = 0; i < updatesToInstall.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("Check4");
                        if (installationRes.GetUpdateResult(i).HResult == 0)
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine("Check5");
                            Console.WriteLine("Instalada : " + updatesToInstall[i].Title);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Instalación Fallida : " + updatesToInstall[i].Title);
                        }

                        Console.Write("pause");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Si ocurre algún error, lo imprimimos 
                Console.WriteLine("Exception", e);
            }
        }

        //Función para crear Excel con lista de actualiaciones
        static public void Generate_PDF(string[] list, string Path)
        {
            string lista = "<tr>" + "<td> Date </td>" + "<td> Title </td>" + "<td> KBId </td>" + "<td> Size (MB) </td>" + "</tr>";
            //Hacemos Split
            int i = 2;
            foreach (string upd in list)
            {
                lista = lista + "<tr>";
                string[] celdas = upd.Split('|');
                int j = 1;
                foreach (string celda in celdas)
                {
                    lista = lista + "<td>" + celda + "</td>";
                    j++;
                }
                lista = lista + "</tr>";
                i++;
            }

            //Guardamos el documento
            string filename = Path.Replace("\\", "\\\\");

            //Creamos un nuevo documento PDF
            //PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
            //document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

            //Creamos una página vacía
            //PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

            //Generamos un objeto XGraphics para dibujar
            //XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

            //Creamos la fuente
            //XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

            //Dibujamos el texto
            //gfx.DrawString(lista, font, XBrushes.Black,
            //new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
            //XStringFormats.Center);

            PdfDocument  document = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf("<html><table class= 'egt'>" + lista+ "</table></html>", PageSize.A4);
            document.Save(filename);
            //PdfDocument document = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf("<p><h1>Hello World</h1>This is html rendered text</p>", PageSize.A4);
            //document.Save("D:\\File.pdf");

            //document.Save(filename);
        }

        //FUNCION PRINCIPAL
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Creamos los argumentos de línea de comandos
            CommandLineParser.CommandLineParser parser = new CommandLineParser.CommandLineParser();
            ValueArgument<string> Opciones = new ValueArgument<string>('o', "opciones", "GetUpdates, Download or Install");
            ValueArgument<string> Path = new ValueArgument<string>('p', "Path", "Ruta Excel con lista actulizaciones");
            parser.Arguments.Add(Opciones);
            parser.Arguments.Add(Path);
            parser.ParseCommandLine(args);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("INDRA SOLUCIONES TI - WINTEL - Actualizaciones pendientes");
            Console.WriteLine("Seleccion: " + Opciones.Value);
            if (Opciones.Value == "GetUpdates")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ruta seleccionada: " + Path.Value);
            }
            try //recorremos uno a uno los parámetros obtenidos al ejecutar el programa
            {
                //preguntamos si corrimos el programa con el atributo o argumento -Getupdates
                if (Opciones.Value == "GetUpdates")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Listado de actualizaciones pendientes...");
                    string[] list = Get_Updates();
                    Generate_PDF(list, Path.Value);
                    //Generate_PDF(list, @"C:\Users\jpmedinag\Desktop\Desarrollos C#\Windows-Update-Manager Net (PDF)\Windows-Update-Manager\bin\Release\test.pdf");
                }
                //preguntamos si corrimos el programa con el atributo o argumento -descargar
                else if (Opciones.Value == "Download")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Descargando actulaizaciones...");
                    Download_Updates();
                }
                //preguntamos si corrimos el programa con el atributo o argumento -instalar
                else if (Opciones.Value == "Install")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Instalando actualizaciones...");
                    Install_Updates();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new System.InvalidOperationException("ERROR: Parámetros incorrectos. GetUpdates: para obtener una lista en XLSX, Download: para descargar las actualizaciones, Install: para descargar e instalar las actualizaciones");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Environment.Exit(2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use the NuGet's: CommandLineArgumentsParser, LinqBridge, PDFsharp, HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp, and HtmlRenderer.Core.

And for last, I add a reference to de WuapiLib.dll, that is in C:\Windows\System32.

If I compile this in windows 10, the program go fine, but, if I execute it in windows server 2008 standar edition, it throw me the error:

Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or asse
mbly 'Windows-Update-Manager.exe' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is b
uilt by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
File name: 'Windows-Update-Manager.exe'

The Target Platform is .Net 4.0, but if I change to .Net 2.0, The Compiler can't load de reference WuapiLib.dll.

I have put the project here:
https://github.com/erniker/CSHARP

I hope someone could help me. Thanks!!

Comment: Isn't Windows Server 2008 out of support (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-new-options-for-sql-server-2008-and-windows-server-2008-end-of-support/)?  You really don't have to worry about Windows Update for an out of support OS

Comment: Hi Flydog57. However, I run the program in a Windows 2008 R2 with ,Net 4.6 installed, and go fine, even show a list of pending updates... all in all, I would like know to fix it, even windows 2008 was out of support, just for fun XD